# Caching a method that's got conditional output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms, refinery

I have a method with is used to render news articles on every page. If you aren't on a care home page then it won't render specific news to that home. It's quite a heavy thing to process on every single page request. I was wondering if anyone could come up with a good way of caching it.

```
def articles_to_show
  @articles = @care_home ? @care_home.news_items.latest.translated.limit(4).includes(:images) : Refinery::News::Item.latest.hidden_from_main.translated.limit(4).includes(:images)
end
```

Here's the view template - http://pastebin.com/BAmgSZia

I've tried fragment caching it, but then I realised every now and then if it expires and the first request is that of a care home, then the news articles will be populated incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have ugly code already so it wouldn't be very bad to make this code a little more obfuscated ...

```
@articles = lambda { YOUR_HEAVY_CODE }
```

Then in your view you're:

```
- cache do
  - @articles = @articles.call
  = #rest of the partial
```

Thing worth mentioning is that, if you can't use any embedded and suggested way of caching, it's probably something wrong with your design.

1. Relating your action instance variable with other instance variable probably initialized in some filter is bad design example.
2. `#articles_to_show` it's bad example of REST approach, you can instead do something like:

   `class Articles::CollectionController` with `show` method
3. Don't use ternarny operator, probably at all, it's so obfuscated. `?:` syntax is proper only for very easy statements.
4. Don't place so much to the controller, try to delegate your methods, scopes by merging them into another method - it would be cleaner

Comment: Indeed it is ugly, unfortunately it's code I've taken over from a previous dev, it's sort of a back burner project that I'm wanting to improve over time. I appreciate the recommendations, that's definitely a better way to go. At the minute that method is actually in the app helper, not even in a controller! The helper method is called on pretty much every page as its view template is rendered everywhere.

Comment: Oh sick...Majority of my answer isn't right because it's a helper. But you can still use lazy loading by blocks. This is problematic approach but works just as the rest of this app ...